# Creating random number in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit, int

I'm trying to create a game in which a projectile is launched at a random angle.
To do this I need to be able to generate two random Int's. I looked up some tutorials and came up with this:

```
var random = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 1500)
var random2 = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % -300)
self.addChild(bullet)
bullet.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake((random2), (random))
```

It worked for a while but now it just crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it crashes, you probably have some more information to share. Where does it crash exactly what does the stack-trace say? It's likely _not_ to do directly with the creation of the random-numbers but something else. (Bullet lacking a physicsBody, or bullet already having a parent for instance).

Comment: Figured this question was more about getting random values and less about the crashing,  nickfalk is probably right that the crashing is unrelated anyway.

Comment: It's definitely the random numbers, I replaced them with normal Ints and it didn't crash.

Comment: Then I would suspect the modulo with a negative number was an issue, but it is very unusual for something in code to 'work for a while' and then start crashing if nothing else changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand very well your issue but I think it could be useful:

```
func getRandomPointFromCircle(radius:Float, center:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
     let randomAngle = Float(arc4random())/Float(UInt32.max-1) * Float(M_PI) * 2.0
     // polar => cartesian
     let x = radius * cosf(theta)
     let y = radius * sinf(theta)
     return CGPointMake(CGFloat(x)+center.x,CGFloat(y)+center.y)
}
```

Comment: arc4random is already ranged to UInt32.max, so the uniform is not neccessary

Answer (score 3):

What I find I use the most is `arc4random_uniform(upperBound)` which returns a random Int ranging from zero to upperBound -1.

```
let random = arc4random_uniform(1500)
let random2 = arc4random_uniform(300) * -1

//pick a number between 1 and 10
let pick = arc4random_uniform(10)+1
```

The lowdown on the arc4 functions: [arc4random man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html)

GameplayKit has a nice class wrapping the arc4 functions: [GameplayKit Randomness](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKARC4RandomSource_Class/)

and a handy reference: [Random Hipster](http://nshipster.com/random/)

Comment: You should also mention about not using modulo arithmetic with arc4random. It creates number distributions that are not equal (ie not random). Anyway :-) good answer.

Comment: The distribution of the arc4random() is not equal, so its not that the numbers aren't random its that some values will show up more often. The arc4_uniform() provides an equal distribution across its range as well as eliminating the need for the modulo calculation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot the `random` in `arc4random_uniform(n)`.  Editing answer.

Comment: Ok, testing it now. BTW you reply FAST.